# Codeigniter not producing array with sub array as expected

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I have the following query in codeigniter which returns a list of students with a sub array named 'accessinfo'.

```
$this->db->select('u.id as user_id, u.firstname, u.lastname, u.email, a.id, a.block, a.expirydate')
        ->from('extended_access a')
        ->join('users u', 'u.id = a.user_id')
        ->order_by('u.lastname');

$result = $this->db->get()->result();

$allStudentExtendedAccess = [];
foreach ($result as $row) {
    $user_id = $row->user_id;
    if (!array_key_exists($user_id, $allStudentExtendedAccess)) {
        $allStudentExtendedAccess[$user_id] = [
            'user_id'    => $user_id,
            'firstname'  => $row->firstname,
            'lastname'   => $row->lastname,
            'email'      => $row->email,
            'accessinfo' => []
        ];
    }

    if ($row->block != null) {
        $allStudentExtendedAccess[$user_id]['accessinfo'][] = [
            'access_id'  => $row->id,
            'block'      => $row->block,
            'expirydate' => $row->expirydate
        ];
    }
}

return $allStudentExtendedAccess;
```

I am trying to return the following output as an array that I can loop through and display results in my view. Whilst I have successfully built my sub array (accessinfo) the main array is made of objects.  How do I change this?  I'm sure it's something straight forward that I've missed.

```
object(stdClass)[32]
 public '3899' => 
   object(stdClass)[33]
     public 'user_id' => string '3899' (length=4)
     public 'firstname' => string 'Lucy' (length=6)
     public 'lastname' => string 'Barton' (length=7)
     public 'email' => string '***@dundee.ac.uk' (length=23)
     public 'accessinfo' => 
       array (size=1)
         0 => 
           object(stdClass)[34]
             ...
 public '3479' => 
   object(stdClass)[35]
     public 'user_id' => string '3479' (length=4)
     public 'firstname' => string 'James' (length=4)
     public 'lastname' => string 'Wilson' (length=8)
     public 'email' => string '***@dundee.ac.uk' (length=27)
     public 'accessinfo' => 
       array (size=2)
         0 => 
           object(stdClass)[36]
             ...
         1 => 
           object(stdClass)[37]
             ...
```

Comment: If I understand the question correctly, you want to get it all as arrays instead of objects? Have you tried changing `->result()` to `->result('array')` or `->result_array()`? https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/results.html#CI_DB_result::result

Comment: I had tried that previously and it then returns errors on line '$user_id = $row->user_id;' . Trying to get property of non-object.  The end goal is to have it all as arrays

Comment: Yes, and using `->result('array')` will give you just that.. an array. Doing `$row->user_id` is how you get a property from an _object_, which obviously won't work on an array. You need to do `$row['user_id']` instead when using `->result('array')` or `->result_array()`.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I am misunderstanding, you don't have to change it. It looks fine. When you iterate through those results just reference objects

```
foreach ($allStudentExtendedAccess as $user_id => $data) {
  // $firstname = $data->firstname;
  // $lastname = $data-> lastname;
  // etc...
  foreach ($data->accessinfo as $accessset) {
    // $access_id =  $accessset->id; 
    // etc ..
  }
}
```

Comment: I've tried changing to `-result('array')` and indeed I can loop through the results however I usually do a check before my loop using `is_array` .  It doesn't pick up that it's an array

Comment: `foreach` can iterate arrays or objects. Usually with arrays you get the index as well as the value as in `foreach ($array as $index => $value)` but with objects you only get the value as in `foreach ($object as $value)`. Did this answer your initial question?